# Jersey role-based entity filtering: Jackson implementation

Tags: java, json, security, jersey, jackson

I have been reading the very interesting [section of the Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html) regarding entity filtering, particularly the section regarding [role-based filtering](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html#ef.security.annotations).

Unfortunately it looks like the feature is only available when using MOXy and support for Jackson is [in the backlog](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2132) for now.

So I was thinking about giving it a shot and writing the required classes to implement Jackson-based security annotation role-based filtering. This doesn't seem like an easy task. I am guessing I would have to register my own `ObjectMapperProvider` for Jackson that returns a wrapper for the Jackson `ObjectMapper` and via "some magic" do the filtering in the wrapper.

Is this a good way to go? Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Jersey 2.16 that has entity filtering support for JSON via Jackson.

reference: http://blog.dejavu.sk/2015/02/04/jerseys-entity-filtering-meets-jackson/

and here is an example of role-based entity filtering: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/entity-filtering-security

Comment: I'm not using Jersey anymore so I don't have the time+motivation to check this myself :) but I have no reason to believe this won't work.

Comment: If you don't mind asking, I am interested to know what did you use as an alternative to Jersey?

Comment: I changed job and programming language. AFAIK the team at my previous job still uses Jersey.